# Memory leak when loading images

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm using the following code to load and resize images.

```
$(imagesToProcess.files).each(function (idx, file) {
                    var img = new Image();
                    img.onload = function (e) {
                        //var resized = _resizeImage(e.target);
                        URL.revokeObjectURL(e.target.src);
                    };
                    img.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
                });
```

This code results in a gigantic memory spike in Chrome, even though I commented out the actual resizing. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does `URL.revokeObjectURL()` do?

Comment: Function creation within a loop is really bad practice.
Try to avoid it firstly

Comment: this post may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7544957/memory-leak-in-javascript-when-using-new-image?rq=1

Comment: @evolutionxbox https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/revokeObjectURL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code, which is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21309760/memory-leaks-when-manipulating-images-in-chrome?rq=1), solved it for me

```
                    var fileQueue = [];
                    var lock = false;
                    var img = new Image();
                    img.onload = function (e) {
                        URL.revokeObjectURL(e.target.src);
                        lock = false;
                    };

                    $(imagesToProcess.files).each(function (idx, file) {
                        fileQueue.push(file);
                    });

                    var processQueue = setInterval(processFile, 250);

                    function processFile() {
                        if (fileQueue.length == 0) {
                            console.log('nothing in queue');
                            clearInterval(processQueue);
                            return;
                        }
                        if (!lock) {
                            img.src = URL.createObjectURL(fileQueue.shift());
                            lock = true;
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: Note: This no longer solves the memory leak in Chrome (tested in v83).

Answer (score 0):

Don't use much of anonymous functions instead use reference of the functions.

```
$(imagesToProcess.files).each(createImage);

function createImage(idx, file){
   var img = new Image();
       img.onload = imageOnload;
       img.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
}
function imageOnload(e) {
    URL.revokeObjectURL(e.target.src);
}
```

In you code for every image creation one instance of function object is created. That is what causing memory leak in your code.

Comment: The code you are showing has the exact same effect on memory. Goes up and up and up.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this memory leak in my program by using an alternate method of jpeg-decoding (using library rather than browser's Image object): https://stackoverflow.com/a/62584068/2441655